# Cannot activate virtual environment on virtual studio

Tags: python, path

I am using Visual Studio Code and have Anaconda downloaded so i selected it as my path interpreter.

I am able to download virtualenv using `pip install virtualenv` and then  instantiate it using `virtualenv env`.

The issue occurs when I try to activate the environment using `activate env` or `conda activate env`.

Error message returned: `Could not find conda environment: env`. I then proceeded to look into my directory and I see that the environment is included as a folder so I'm confused on why I cannot activate it. For reference I am using Windows.

Edit: Originally the environment was not appearing in my users/.conda/environments file but using `conda create --name venv` I was able to create a new environment here. However, it doesn't instantiate in my current directory. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conda virtual environments are not interchangeable with virtualenv virtual environments. If you have created a virtual environment in your current dir. The ps command would be `.\Scripts\activate`

Comment: When I run that I get ```.\Scripts\activate is  not recognized as the name of a cmdlet. /... Please verify that the path is correct and try again.``` my file path is as follows: C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder_name

Comment: are you in the `env` directory?

Comment: ah I i was only in the folder for my directory. I used ```cd env``` and my path changed to ```C:\Users\user\Desktop\file_name\env``` then ran ```.\Scripts\activate```. it returned ```cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system```

Comment: open Powershell as admin -> `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Remotesigned `

Comment: I figured out permission on running scripts using https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2559. then using your solution I was able to activate the environment. Can you give me some more insight onto why i can not simply use ```conda activate env_name```?

Comment: Also just a quick follow up: Now that I have the environment active, how do I deactivate it? ```conda deactivate``` doesn't work, which makes sense as we had to use ```.\Scripts\activate```

Comment: you are not using a conda virtual environment, you are using a virtualenv virtual environment. A conda virtual environment created with: `conda create -n env` 
then started with `conda activate env`

Comment: deactivating virtualenv virtual environments is as easy as: `deactivate`